# Siddhi: Ignore duplicate events while pattern active

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have a [non-occurring event pattern](https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-5.x/query-guide-5.x/#detecting-non-occurring-events) to detect if a certain condition happens, then alert me if that condition doesn't change within a time limit. The below query could be described as "If value 1 appears for a user, alert me if there is not a new value for that user within 5 seconds":

```
define stream inStream(name string, value int);
partition with (name of inStream) 
begin 
    from every in=inStream[ value == 1 ]
    -> not inStream[ not(value == 1) ] for 5 sec
    select in.name, in.value
    insert into outStream;
end;
```

This query works exactly as expected: if I don't receive a value different than 1 within 5 seconds then the query is triggered. The issue arises when there are duplicate events with the value of 1.

If I send the event `{name: "bob", value: 1}` every second for 10 seconds, I would like to see the query triggered twice, once at 5 seconds, and once at 10 seconds. Right now however I see the query being triggered every second starting at 5 seconds in. Essentially the query (working as it should) is starting the 5 second timer for every event with value 1 it sees. However I would like it to not start that timer (or not output at least) if there is already a timer running.

I attempted to solve this with the following query (simply adding an 'output' line):

```
define stream inStream(name string, value int);
partition with (name of inStream) 
begin 
    from every in=inStream[ value == 1 ]
    -> not inStream[ not(value == 1) ] for 5 sec
    select in.name, in.value
    output first every 5 sec
    insert into outStream;
end;
```

I also tried `output last` and `output all`.

The queries above did not work as expected: in the case of `all` and `last` no events at all were output, in the case of `first` only a single event was output, not the subsequent ones after the first 5 second block passed.

Is there any way to achieve what I would like? I have a hunch that using time windows or `output` is the way to solve it, but so far have not been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The second query in the original question ends up working as expected. I was previously on Siddhi 4.1.4. After upgrading to Siddhi 5.0.0 the query works as I wanted it to.